# Is image stitching with a fundamental matrix, instead of a homography, possible?

Tags: homography, image-stitching

I would like to ask a question I already asked on the OpenCV board but did not get an answer to: http://answers.opencv.org/question/189206/questions-about-the-fundamental-matrix-and-homographies/.

After learning about the fundamental matrix I have the following question that I could not answer by googling. The fundamental matrix is a more general case of the homography as it is independent of scene's structure. So I was wondering if it could be used for image stitching instead of a homography. But all papers I found only use homographies. So I reread the material about the properties of the fundamental matrix and now I am wondering:

Is it not possible to use the fundamental matrix for stitching because of its rank deficiency and the fact that it does only relate points in Image 1 to lines (epipolar lines) in Image 2?

Another question I have regarding homographies: All papers I read about image stitching use homographies for rotational panoramas. What if I want to create a panorama based only on translation between images? Can I use the homography as well? The answers provided by a google search vary quite a lot.

Kind regards and thanks for your help!

Conundraah

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Is it possible?" is not a very good question here - it would be much better if you ask a "How to" question instead so you get more than a yes or no response. It also helps to include what you have tried in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and hints. :-) Granted, my question is a bit off for Stack Overflow but unfortunately I need to know the answer to my question before I can start coding. And since I stumbled upon some well answered questions, remotely similar to mine, I thought I try my luck. Furthermore I think that, at least in my case, the answer to "is it possible to...?" is very similar to "how to...?". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. About using fundamental matrix for stitching.

   It actually depends on how you want to stitch the image together.
   The problem is even if you get the fundamental matrix, when you stitch images together, you will only need homography matrix to do the transformation of images. So what is the point of using fundamental matrix. Unless you figure out how to handle the different distance on the same image.
2. In the case of panorama images, the assumption is that the scene structure is far enough to be seen as planar, so comparatively the translation could be ignored. If that is not the case, translation could be considered.